# Я занимаюсь функцией вызова на бой и его отклонением для своего проекта

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Сначала всё работало нормально, но когда я добавил функцию проверки отправителя(у человека, которому бросили вызов есть 2 варианта ответа да или нет и отвечать может только он(да пока я не делал т.к. я ещё не продумал механики боя) бот на команды перестал реагировать. Подскажите что делать пожалуйста.

```
#вызов
@client.command(pass_context=True)

async def battle(ctx, member: discord.Member):
  author=ctx.message.author
  enemy=member.mention
  await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)

  await ctx.send(f'{enemy}, вам бросает вызов{author.mention}!. ^yes ли ^no')
  @client.command(pass_context=True)
  async def no(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == enemy:   
       await ctx.send(f'{enemy} отклонил(-а) запрос.') 
    else:
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def battle(ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention}, вам бросает вызов {ctx.author.mention}!. ^yes ли ^no')

    def check(m):
        return m.author == member and m.channel == ctx.channel
    
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        if msg.content == '^yes':
            # battle
        else:
            # decline
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.send('vremya vishlo')
```